# Sleeping MySQL connections due to used PDO class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use my PDO class in other class by calling them in the constructor

```
class{
    private $db;

    __constructor(){
        $this->db = new db;
    }
}
```

I assume that this creates a lot of sleeping MySQL proccesses.
[image: MySQL processes]

What can I do to avoid those sleeping processes? Is any new instance of the PDO class one sleeping process?

Comment: When you create a new connection, it will stay open and asleep until you close it or the php page finishes loading.

Comment: Is it possible that your PDO class uses [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#example-980)?

Comment: `__constructor` that's an outright error. RTM http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @JiriHrazdil That was my thought too, but no.

Comment: First, add a destructor that sets $this->db = null;  Next, check to see if you are using persistent connections, if so, then those are not a concern, they are just waiting around for the next connection request.

Comment: We don't know what your `db` class does, but if instantiating it as `new db()` creates a new connection rather than reuse an old one (such as with a singleton), you may be creating new connections for each object that makes use of `db`. That is a common mistake, but not possible to tell with the limited code posted.  Eventually though, it can use up the system's available connections and start to produce fatal errors intermittently.